# Prove that $t$ does not have multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{C}[t]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Stewart's Galois Theory Chapter 4.2 he mentioned that we can perform the operations of addition, subtraction, and multiplication in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[t]$ but usually not division because $C[t]$ does not contain an inverse $t^{-1}$ for $t$ and he asked us to prove in the exercise. Isn't it just that $C[t]$ does not contain an inverse $t^{-1}$ for $t$...I'm not sure how he means to "prove" this? Thanks!

Comment: It means that you need to show that for any element $p \in C[t]$, it is not true that $t \cdot p = 1$.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Isn't it just that $C[t]$ does not contain an inverse $t^{-1}$ for $t$"?

Comment: @user so I let $p(t) = a_0 + a_1 t + \ldots + a_nt^n$ such that $h(t) = p(t) t =  a_0t + a_1 t^2 + \ldots + a_nt^{n+1} = 1$. The degree of $h(t)$ is $\ge 1$ but the degree of $1$ is $0$ so this there cannot be such $p(t)$. How does this look?

Comment: @Shiyue Yes, that's a fine approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, how do you know that $t^{-1}$ is not in $C[t]$? Remember that $t^{-1}$ just means "that element of $C[t]$ that if you multiply by $t$ you get $1$." It's true that if you were in the *field* $C(t)$ (or dealing with functions in general) then the inverse should be the rational function $1/t$, and this doesn't look like a polynomial. But how do you know for sure? After all, how do you know I'm not really, *really* clever and can write it as a polynomial?

You start with some polynomial $p \in C[t]$ and show that $t p(t) \ne 1$. This is most easily done by noting that the degree of the product is the sum of the degrees.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose we have $tp(t) = 1$ for every $t$. Calculate in $0$, you get $0\cdot p(0) = 1$. Contraddiction.

Comment: Indeed. More formally, we consider the ring homomorphism $\Bbb C[t]\to \Bbb C$ induced by $t\mapsto 0$, but then again that is just high-brow-speak for "plug in $0$".

Answer (score 2):

Any element of $\mathbb{C}[t]$ is of the form $p(t)=a_0+a_1 t+...+a_nt^n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ and $a_i\in \mathbb{C}$ for $i$ from $0,..,n$. If $t$ had an inverse, then we would have $p(t)\in\mathbb{C}[t]$ such that $t.p(t)=1$. But degree$(t.p(t))\geq 1$, which gives us a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{C}[t]$ is set of polynomials (over ...); so can think only about polynomials in $t$. Since $t^{-1}$ is *not a polynomial in $t$*, we can not consider directly it in the set $\mathbb{C}[t]$.

We have to proceed like: consider a polynomial $p(t)$ and see why $p(t).t$ can not be $1$. Can you see? [Hint: compare degrees].